# piping interval observable and passed as input as async pipe is not rendering in template

Tags: angular, asynchronous, input, rxjs

Say i have some data that's retrieved from somewhere in a continuous manner; this data is processed and passed through an Input() which is consumed with an async pipe inside a child component that-s *ngFor'ed;

the observable could be

```
getObservable(param: string): Observable<string> {
    return timer(1000)
    .pipe(
      map(v => {
        console.log(v);
        return param;
      } )
    )
  }
```

which is passed as input in the child component list

`<hello *ngFor="let hi of hellos" [name]="getObservable(hi)"></hello>`

which is an Observable that is managed through the `async` pipe

`<h1>Hello {{name | async}}!</h1>`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-51mxua

1. Why don't i get this data in the component?
2. What can i do to get the data in the component using this approach (aka not change the hello component, but fix it upstream, preferably not storing state in the parent component)?

Comment: FYI SO guidelines tell you to put your code in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this isn't working because of how angular runs change detection.  It keeps rerunning that getObservable() function over and over and un/resubscribing so it never actually hits that 1000ms timeout.

do this instead:

```
observable$;

constructor() {
  this.observable$ = this.getObservable();
}
```

and pass observable$ to the component.  This change detection feature is also why you should generally never put function calls in templates. it's a performance hazard.

there are a lot of ways to do this, but generally you need to make sure your observable assignment is only run once, and that will not happen with a template function call.

based on your edit, you would do it like this:

```
constructor() {
  this.hellos = this.hellos.map(hello => 
                                Object.assign(hello, {observable$: this.getObservable(hello)});
}

<hello *ngFor="let hi of hellos" [name]="hi.observable$"></hello>
```

you could also contrive some system of passing in both the function and it's arguments to the child:

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() param: any;
  @Input() fn$: (param: any) => Observable<string>;
  name: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.fn$(this.param);
  }
}
```

in parent template:

```
<hello *ngFor="let hi of hellos" [fn$]="getObservable" [param]="hi"></hello>
```

be warned this may have issues if your function makes use of injected services and you'll need to bind the context.

Comment: thanks for this, but isn't there another pattern that would not have me store a component class member? I understand this is not really "state" but how can' i set up either the child or the parent component to not have this approach? What if i have 100 child components, with each one of them getting its own observable based on some argument? It means that observable$ member will always be overwritten and passed to the child?

Comment: you're gona need to add a little more detail about your specific use case to your question, preferably with a concrete example of what you're after.

Comment: answer updated to reflect.  You just need to figure a way to ensure observable assignment occurs once and only once, that said, you could theoretically fix this in other ways by modifying the child component by passing both the parameter and the function to get the observable to the child and having the child build the stream.

Comment: the edit i made was to show that the observable that the child component requests can be different based on some argument; what if that array member is not there, and it's retrieved after a backend call? What i'm getting to is asking: Is there absolutely no other way than storing a local member to the parent component?

Comment: there is no way to make it work by having a function call in template. You MUST ensure that the observable assignment occurs once and only once. I updated my answer to show another possible method modifying the child.  There are 100 ways to make this work in an efficient DRY fashion, but it will be tailored to your specific case. If the array member is not there initially, then you need to write a stream that sets the observables when that array becomes available.

Comment: the better question here might be, why are you architecting in this fashion? having observables passed to the children and subscribing there instead of just using the async pipe in the parent and building your observables there.  at some point, the stream needs to be fully built, it sounds to me like you're trying to do it too late in the game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196283/discussion-between-vzr-and-bryan60).

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your AppComponent like this:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  name = 'Angular';
  obs$: Observable<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.obs$ = this.getObservable();
  }

  getObservable(): Observable<string> {
    return timer(1000)
    .pipe(
      map(v => {
        console.log(v);
        return 'this should show right';

      } )
    )
  }

}
```

And template like this:

```
<hello [name]="obs$"></hello>
```

See updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crvjrf?file=src/app/app.component.html